# Responsive navigation menu with React and Bootstrap - hamburger isn't working

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, hamburger-menu

I created a simple navigation menu with Bootstrap. It's working fine in pure javascript, but when adapting it into react, the hamburger icon doesn't function (nothing happens on click). I installed bootstrap with

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

And then added the bootstrap css to index.html in the public folder:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
```

My jsx is as follows:

```
       <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div className="container">
          <button className="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"><span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/app/portfolio" className="nav-link">PORTFOLIO</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/app/about" className="nav-link">ABOUT</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="#create-head-section" className="nav-link" style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>Personal art</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="#share-head-section" className="nav-link">CONTACT</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Again, everything looks fine except that the hamburger icon is not functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap events require jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap.js [source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/). That page will also let you know which components require JS. You can include jQuery, Popper and bootstrap.js in the `index.html` file, where you load your bundle.  Either add that, or simply check out  [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navs/), which implements Bootstrap components in React.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's working
Just added the "script src..." to the body of index.html in the public folder

Answer (score 5):

The bootstrap **show** class is used to display the collapsible menu items. So, the task is to simply add the **show** class conditionally on click of the hamburger icon.
Just follow these simple steps to achieve this functionality.

Add a showCollapsedMenu(the name is up to you) property with initial value of false in your state like this:

```
state={
    showCollapsedMenu: false
}
```

Then declare a function like this which when called will reverse the current state:

```
toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({
      showCollapsedMenu: !this.state.showCollapsedMenu
    })
}
```

The above function will be called whenever the hamburger icon is clicked. So implement the onCLick method on the hamburger icon like this:

```
<button
  className="navbar-toggler"
  type="button"
  onClick={this.toggleMenu}    // <=
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarNav">
  <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Now create a const show which will conditionally add the show class depending on the state of showCollapsedMenu:

```
const show = (this.state.showCollapsedMenu) ? "show" : "" ;
```

Now finally add this show to the div with collapse navbar class like this:

```
<div className={"collapse navbar-collapse " + show} id="navbarNav">
```

**Note:** Mixing jQuery with React is not recommended as they both manipulate the DOM differently. While it may seem an easy solution, it might result in bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap#whats-included, the npm version of Bootstrap doesn't include jQuery, but the navbar component needs it, so you might need to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery to your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks I just added the scripts to the body of index.html